# How to retrieve depth of menu into template

Tags: menus, templates

In [wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) i use for the menu, with custom walker, i can get the $depth parameter in the start_el function

```
function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args)
```

but, outside this wp_nav_menu(), how can i get the depth of the menu for the clicked item ?
For instance :

- **Home**
- **level1menuelement1**   -level2menuelement1 (first element of first submenu) -level2menuelement2 (second element of first submenu)
- **level1menuelement2**
- ...

In that case, i want to know if my post is in a level 1 or not, to display a specific block or not.

Is there a codex function allowing to facilitate the retrieving of this depth or is it achieved programmatically ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need this to work for CSS and/or Javascript or for PHP?

Comment: I didn't even think of a javascript solution until you mentioned it. It could do the trick (with the "current-menu-item" positioning). I'll check into that. Though it might be a "dirtier" or rather less clean solution than a php one : with js i would only hide the block.

Comment: `if ($j('.current-menu-ancestor').length == 0){$j('#myblock').hide();}`

This works for me.
But if you have a php solution, i'll be glad to have it for learning purpose.

Comment: Given that you want to know what is "clicked" there is no real PHP solution, unless by "clicked" you mean something like "the page I am on".

Comment: Exactly. Let's say i've got a page 1 called when i click on level1menuelement1 and a page 2 called for level2menuelement1. Then, when i'm on page 1, i'm on the top level menu, so i hide in js (or doesn't display in php) the specific block, but when i'm on page 2, i'm not on the top level menu so i display (not hide) the block.
I asked this since i didn't see anything usable related to the corresponding menu element in the query for a page.

Comment: I am getting more confused the more you explain :) I am pretty sure this is best done with CSS and/or Javascript. Voting to close.

Comment: i'm ashamed now :)
You can consider this question closed then since you gave me idea of js use.
Just for learning's sake, i'll try one last time : 
i have a standard menu whose item are pages. When i click on a menu item, i display the corresponding page.
My question could be **how to get the relation between the page and the menu item ? = is there a WP function telling this page is linked to this menu item which has or hasn't a parent**
in wp_postmeta there is `_menu_item_object_id`, `_menu_item_menu_item_parent` giving these informations, but build a custom query seems overkill...

Answer (score 1):

> how to get the relation between the page and the menu item ? = is
>   there a WP function telling this page is linked to this menu item
>   which has or hasn't a parent

Inside the walker, inside the `start_el` method (which you mentioned), `$item->object_id` is the page ID.

Otherwise, you need to pull the menu...

```
$locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
$nav_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($locations['your-menu-location']);
```

... and loop over that array to match up the current page ID with the `object_id` in `$nav_menu` data... if I understand you and I am still not sure that I do.