# List child pages of a specific page

Tags: navigation, child-pages

I'm looking for a snippit/function that will list the child pages of a specific page (I guess by page ID) but not necessarily when you are on that page or a child of that page. The parent page (Parents Area) and its child pages are listed below:

```
Parents Area
- Term Dates
- Calendar
- School Blog
- Letters to Parents
- Attendance
```

I want to be able to be on any page of the website, specifically within single posts and post archives but be able to list out just the children of the parent page "Parents Area".

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: The code for which part? I don't have any code for this functionality just yet. I've got my code (functions.php) to output my subnav across the rest of the site which works perfectly: http://pastebin.com/HKeyqjXE

I need to do exactly the same thing, but for a specified page ID regardless of what page I'm on.

Comment: As written, I can't help but consider this "work for me for free". [You are expected to have researched the problem and made an attempt at solving it before posting a question.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) There are a lot of "list child pages" questions to the right under "RELATED". Why don't you try to get yourself started and [edit] the question so that it addresses some more specific problem that you encounter.

Comment: That's OK, I understand. I'm just not sure where to start on this one. Am I best off amending my code above, or is this a rather long way of doing it just for this task?

Comment: At least add more detail. What is that structure above? Is that hierarchical pages? Is that particular menu? This may perhaps be related: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/105495/21376 Or this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100226/21376

Comment: Again, apologies. I'll explain the context. Within any blog section of the website i.e. blog page, single posts etc. I want to display just the 1st level child pages of a particular parent of the website. I'll update the hierarchical list of pages in the OP to provide better detail.

Comment: OK, I've updated my original post to provide a more accurate description of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To list subpages of a particular page, use [`wp_list_pages`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages) with `child_of` argument.

```
$parent_page_id = 42;
wp_list_pages( array(
    'child_of' => $parent_page_id
) );
```

Comment: Awesome, that was all I needed! Sorry, still learning my way around the WP functions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I didn't quite get what was asked for, but what's wrong in using [`wp_list_pages`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages)?

Here is a sample code (which most probably has to be customized and adapted to fit your needs):

```
<ul>
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'depth' => 1,
        'include' => YOUR PAGE ID HERE,
        'title_li' => '',
    );
    wp_list_pages($args);
    $args['child_of'] = $args['include'];
    unset($args['include']);
    wp_list_pages($args);
    ?>
</ul>
```

Maybe you have to adapt the HTML list as well, if you want a hierarchical list of two levels etc.